# Bash terminal closes after running a script

Tags: bash, unix

I am running the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
argumente=$#

if [ $argumente -ne 2 ]
then    echo "Trebuie dati doi parametri"
fi

if test -e $1
then    if  test -e $2
        then
                fisier1="$1"
                fisier2="$2"
                exec 0< $fisier1
                exec 1> $fisier2
                tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
        else echo "Nu exista al doilea fisier dat ca argument"
        fi
else echo nu    
fi
```

And it outputs the right thing, but after that, the terminal closes itself. 
I think It`s because I redirected the output.
**How can I redirect the output back to the terminal after script ends?**

Comment: How do you execute that script? `sh script.sh` or `./script.sh` or `. script.sh`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're sourcing the script by running it via

```
. scriptname arg1 arg2
```

You have to execute the script like this

```
./scriptname arg1 arg2
```

Comment: Did that. Still the same.

Comment: @user2997779 How are you running the script from your terminal?

Comment: I enter: ". scriptname argument1"

Comment: @user2997779 that is your problem, you have to run it with ./scriptname argument1 ... I will edit my post